# Calculating year to date percentage change of macro series

Tags: r, percentage

Thanks for clicking on this thread. I have done a bit of digging but still couldn’t find a solution.

The whole idea is that if you have a dataset that has a column on date and several columns on macroeconomic variables (stock indices etc). How could you extract the year to date percentage change for each of the macro variable?

I suppose the idea should be to extract the row of the start date and the current date from the dataset and calculate the change then put them in a table.

Using the “economics” sample, and suppose that the current date is 1968 April, the output should calculate the percentage difference of, say, pop at 1967-12-01 and 1968-4-1.

The main issue is that I cannot extract the row based on the specific date. I tried to use economics[date == “1967-12-1”] and no result was returned.

Comment: What's your desired output please show at least 2-3 rows for given case i.e. `present date = Apr 1968`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
economics[economics$date == as.Date('1967-12-1'),]

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  date         pce    pop psavert uempmed unemploy
  <date>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 1967-12-01  525. 199657    11.8     4.8     3018
```